# Displaying alternate column when using foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have an issue regarding PHP, MySql and foreign keys. I understand foreign keys and have a relationship between two tables in place as described:

Let's say I have 2 tables: '*vehicles*' and '*manufacturers*'.

Each row in the '*vehicles*' table includes a manufacturerId column which is a foreign key relating to the '*manufacturers*' table. This is set up nicely, in PhpMyAdmin when I insert a new row into the '*vehicles*' table the manufacturerId column has a drop-down menu with the manufacturerId's listed as options. Very nice.

BUT: In my application, of course, I don't want the user to have to know (or have to guess) what the correct number for 'Ford' or 'BMW' is when they add a new vehicle, I want them to be able to choose the manufacturer by name.

But how does the application know the manufacturer names based on the manufacturerId? How does the application know there is a relationship between the 2 tables? Am I supposed to hard-code the relationship in the application? Am I supposed to modify all my queries to have a JOIN between the 2 tables? Or hard-code a query to get a list of manufacturers every time I want to display a drop-down of manufacturers?

Is there a way for the application to know about relationships between tables and be able to display data from a text column instead of the int column used as the ID?

Comment: Am I supposed to modify all my queries to have a JOIN between the 2 tables? (Yep)  Or hard-code a query to get a list of manufacturers every time I want to display a drop-down of manufacturers? (Yep/Nope) I'd write one object with different methods to obtain such data.

Comment: yes, I was a bit misleading there, I have a class that wraps that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 2 table are structured like this:

```
VEHICLES
id
manufacturerId
vehicleName

MANUFACTURERS
id
manufacturerName
```

You would create your vehicle manufacturer select menu for users by querying the database like this:

```
// query the database
$q = 'SELECT id, manufacturerName FROM manufacturers';
$r = mysqli_query($link, $q);

// display a select menu using id and manufacturerName  
echo '<select name="manufacturer">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['manufacturerName'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

To use the post data from that menu to add a vehicle & manufacturer id to your vehicles table:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO vehicles (manufacturerId, vehicleName) VALUES ({$_POST['manufacturer']}, '{$_POST['vehicleName']}')";
mysqli_query($link, $q);
```

Finally, if you wish to select the vehicle name and manufacturer in the same query, you would join the tables like this:

```
// Select vehicle name and manufacturer for vehicle with id of 1
$q = "SELECT v.vehicleName, m.manufacturerName, v.id AS vehicleId, m.id AS manufacturerId
    FROM vehicles AS v, manufacturers AS m 
    WHERE v.manufacturerID = m.id
    AND v.id = 1";
mysqli_query($link, $q);
```

I think that should answer all your questions in one way or another!

Comment: That's what I was hoping to avoid. I was hoping I might be able to use DESCRIBE to find where the foreign keys are, and then be able to SELECT values from the foreign table to use along side the foreign keys.

I suppose I will have to do it the way you described, unless someone comes up with a better idea.